# Firefox not displaying a horizontal list properly

Tags: css, firefox, html-lists

I'm creating a gallery site for a friend. The galleries should be displayed in a horizontal list, and should overflow so it can scroll left to right. It works fine in **Chrome**, but displays vertically in **Firefox**.

You can see it live [here](http://ayrron.nicholasradford.com). With [CSS](https://gist.github.com/1675968)

Comment: For some reason I haven't tried to find yet, all the `li`s have `display: block` in Firefox.

Comment: That's probably because I'm using jQuery.fadeIn() on the elements.

Comment: You  probably want to use "float: left;" on the li elements instead of "display: inline-block;".

Comment: A working but unclean fix is to add `!important` to `body div.container ul.gallery_container li.gallery { display: inline-block; }`.

Comment: @BenLee, any particular reason?

Comment: @thirtydot, That would likely work, but I could also not hide and display the `li`s themselves, but instead hide and show the `ul`

Comment: @NickRadford, only because I know from experience that floats tend to be robust across browsers. If I could give you a better reason than that, I'd post an answer =).

Comment: @BenLee, `float: left;` still produces the vertical list, but that's likely because all of the `li`s were being set inline to `style="display:block"` thanks to jQuery.

Comment: Well, elements have to be "block" for float to work correctly, so that's not the problem. You probably have to do some more work in addition. There's plenty of example css online if you search for `horizontal li css float` on google.

Comment: it seems working fine in firefox.........

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, `jQuery.fadeIn()` (and the other derivative show methods) add `style="display:block"` to the DOM element you call it on, sometimes producing erratic results in Firefox.

Calling `jQuery.fadeIn()` on the `ul` instead of the `li` produces the correct result.